# How to continue two type of loop at a time using Javascript and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, loops, foreach

I need one help.i need to continue 2 types of loop at a time using Javascript and PHP.Let me to explain my code and scenario as well.

```
<script>

  function addQuestionField(){
    var get =$("#ques").val();
    if(get==null || get==''){
        alert('Please add no of questions');
    }else{
        var counter = 0;
        if (counter > 0){
            return;
        }else{
             counter++;
              <?php
                   $status=array("status"=>'1');
                   $feeddata=$db->kf_answertype->find($ustatus); 
            ?>
             for(var i=1;i<get;i++){
                 $('#container').append(' <textarea class="form-control" name="questions'+ i +'" id="questions" placeholder="Questions"  style="background:#FFFFFF;"  rows="2"><?php if($_REQUEST['edit']) { echo $getcustomerobj->questions; } else { echo $_REQUEST['questions']; } ?></textarea>');

                 <?php
                 foreach($feeddata as $v){
                 ?>
                 $('#subcontainer').append(' <input type="radio" name="answer_type0" id="answer_type0" value="<?php echo $v['_id']; ?>"> <?php echo $v['answertype']; ?>');
                 <?php
                 }
                 ?>
             }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Here i have one for loop but inside this one foreach loop is still there .By doing this in one iteration of for loop foreach loop continuing many times which i dont need.Here i need each time of `for` loop the `foreach` loop also iterate.suppose for 1st iteration  of `for` loop the `foreach` loop also iterate once and so on.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Use [current](http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php) and [next](http://php.net/manual/en/function.next.php) functions to get consistent elements of an array. So, this fragment of your code

```
foreach($feeddata as $v){
?>
    $('#subcontainer').append(' <input type="radio" name="answer_type0" id="answer_type0" value="<?php echo $v['_id']; ?>"> <?php echo $v['answertype']; ?>');
<?php
}
?>
```

should be changed to

```
$('#subcontainer').append(' <input type="radio" name="answer_type0" id="answer_type0" value="<?php echo current($feeddata)['_id']; ?>"> <?php echo current($feeddata)['answertype']; ?>');
<?php next($feeddata); ?>
```

or, if you use old version of php do it in such way:

```
<?php $v = current($feeddata); ?>
    $('#subcontainer').append(' <input type="radio" name="answer_type0" id="answer_type0" value="<?php echo $v['_id']; ?>"> <?php echo $v['answertype']; ?>');
<?php next($feeddata); ?>
```